# How to truncate a list if condition is satisfied

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values and basically I want to go through the list, and check if I have more than 20 consecutive values below a certain minimum. If that is true I want to end the list where the last number above minimum was.

I tried the following with no success :

```
for j in range(0,len(List)):
    if all(k<minimumthreshold for k in List[j:j+20]):
        List= [e for e in List if e != j]
```

Comment: Are you restricted to using vanilla Python, or can you perhaps use something like NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should so something like this -
(Consider this as a  pseudo-code)

```
your_list = [.....]
counter = 0
stop_at = 20  #Set it accordingly
minimum = 30  # Set it accordingly
split_at_index = None
for index, list_item in enumerate(your_list):
    if list_item < minimum:
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 0
        continue
    if counter == stop_at:
        split_at_index = index
        break
new_list = your_list[:split_at_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_list = [12,34,41,145,11,43,123,32]
counter = 0
limit = 3
thresold = 50
index = 0
split = 0
for num in _list:
    if num < thresold:
        counter = counter + 1
        print counter
        if counter == limit:
            split = index
            break
    else:
        counter = 0
    index = index + 1

print (_list[:split])
```